# Background with repeat-y is not expanding with contents

Tags: html, css

I need your help. I have been searching on similar problems in StackOverflow and other sources as well. But for some reason I still could not able to solve my problem. I am not sure what I am missing but it must be something. I have a div with a background image repeat-y. But after the height of that specific div, the background image is not repeating anymore.

So here is my CSS

```
html{
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(../images/bg.gif);
    background-position:top left;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
body{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    height: 100%;
}
.content_middle_border {
    width: 859px;
    min-height: 485px;
    background: url(../images/content_middle_border.jpg) repeat-y;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
#content{
    width:859px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have content_middle_border div in #content div. However, after contents exceed 485px, the background of repeat-y is not repeating. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you mind putting this in a [**JSFiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net)? You will have to provide absolute links to the pictures so we can see them: [**You can upload them to imgur**](http://www.imgur.com) if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by this

```
.content_middle_border {
    width: 859px;
    min-height: 485px;
    background: url(../images/content_middle_border.jpg) repeat-y;
    overflow: inherit; /*Newly added this line*/
}
```

So the div will inherit its #content div. Thank you.